# Why is this returning false? (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I can't figure out why data is returning false here. I have the console log statement and it's telling me there isn't data. I'm searching for a document with 'userId' which is the id of the person sending the message/command which is also in every document to differentiate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
module.exports.addItem = async (userId, item) => {

    profileSchema.findOne(userId, async(err, data)=> {

        console.log('There is data: ' + !!data)

        if(data) {
            const hasItem = Object.keys(data.items).includes(item)

            console.log('Has item: ' + !!hasItem)

            if(!hasItem) {
                data.items[item] = 1
            }
            else {
                data.items[item]++
            }
            await profileSchema.findOneAndUpdate(userId, data)
        }
```

Comment: maybe change the query to:`profileSchema.findOne({"userId": userId},`

Comment: have you checked what `err` is? I would guess there's been an error of some kind with the query

Comment: `const profile = await profileSchema.findOne(userId);`, since its in an `async` function. The returned value will be `null` (or `undefined`), when the query doesn't find a match _or_ the profile document from the database.. The error handling needs to be in a `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your data model or what libraries are you using, but I think the issue is `profileSchema.findOne(userId, async(err, data)=> {...})`.

You should use an actual query as the first parameter, e.g. `profileSchema.findOne({userId: userId}, async(err, data)=> {...})` (or, using the shorthand version, `profileSchema.findOne({ userId }, async(err, data)=> {...})`)